# Mindstorms Chromebook app Stuck in Zoomed-Out Position

Tags: mindstorms, software, labview

We are using the LEGO Mindstorms app on Chromebooks. Our test program got zoomed-out to the point of being too small to read.

The remainder of the screen is normal sized. We've tried using 2 fingers to zoom-in and out, but to no avail. Any suggestions?

Comment: _I haven't used a Chromebook yet, so this might be silly, but:_ Do you have any access to a keyboard, either physical or on-screen? If so, `ctrl-0` is a common "reset zoom" keyboard shortcut.

Answer (score 1):

**SHORT ANSWER:**

Look in upper right hand corner of your project page and find the icon that looks like this [**1:1**] and click it.  It will center and reset the zoom of your program.

[image]
Isn't two finger zooming an *Apple* touch screen thing, like we do on an iPhone?  So, unless you're used to doing this on your Apple tablet at home, the two finger slide technique won't work on the class *Chromebook*.

---

**LONGER ANSWER:**

A few disclaimers first, I don't have a Chromebook, or any LEGO Mindstorms sets... (yet), so I can't be totally sure of what you mean or every detail I say.  So, with that said, let's dance!

---

So, I watched a video of *[cool teacher Mr. Hino](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=iwTLNRruGDM&t=115s)*, downloading the *Windows* version of this app on his class *Chromebook*.

So, to understand your question further, I downloaded the same *Windows* version app on to my PC, and have installed/launched the program.

Assuming your app is the same as my app, I took some screen shots to point out where the Zoom In/Out stuff is.

[image]
1) So, this picture is the Lobby/Row of Robots when we start up the program.

2) We need to get to a "Project".  Located in upper left hand corner. Click to pull down the menu.

3) We'll either choose to start a "New Project", or if we have one saved,   "Open Project" that already exists.

[image]
4) This picture is where you're *zoom-stuck*.

[image]
5) Look in the upper right hand corner and you'll see some icons in a row.

6) You'll see magnifying glasses with "-" sign, "+" sign, and "1:1" zoom reset.

7) Click "1:1" Zoom Reset.

[image]

8) *FRIGGEN-FIXED*!

**EXTRA CREDIT ANSWER:**

There are keyboard combinations called shortcuts that make life *hella*-easier.

The most common are:

"CTRL + C" = Copy.

"CTRL + X" = Cut.

"CTRL + V" = Paste.

Don't know if your Chromebook has a mouse wheel, but...

"CTRL + Mouse wheel UP" = Zoom IN.

"CTRL + Mouse wheel DOWN" = Zoom OUT.

Comment: The desktop app is not the same as the chrome app, so this doesn't really answer the question.

Comment: Hey, Dave. How's it going, my friend.  Yea, my suggestion is based on Mr. Hino's video showing him downloading the Win installer to his Chromebook.  I don't know, maybe he lied;).  Well, I installed the student educational class version. Besides not having a hall of Robots in the Lobby, the class app still has the magnifying/size reset icons in the upper right hand corner.  Hey, David, if you have access to a Chromebook can you please try either Ctrl+, Ctrl-, or Ctrl+0, (Suggested by Joe Friedrichsen, good man!), and get back to us with anything that really helps answer her question?